# Best way to set up CruiseControl for IIS 5.1 dev box and IIS6 server

Tags: .net, svn, iis, cruisecontrol.net

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this. From reading the FAQs at cruisecontrol, it appears that you should develop in the same environment as you produce.

But i have Windows XP (which only runs IIS 5.1) on my dev machine and the server is 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a similar setup that we have been using successfully over a year now. Our CC.Net server is on a Windows 2003 server and all development happens on Windows XP/Vista machines. Code checked into SVN is pulled down onto the Windows 2003 server, built and pushed onto our hosting boxes.